# Background jobs are not clean when script exit

Tags: bash, sh

I want to kill background jobs after the execution of script.

```sh
main.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
sh child.sh
trap 'jobs -p | xargs -r kill' EXIT
```

```sh
child.sh
#!/bin/bash
yes > /dev/null &
```

I want to kill all child process, created by `child.sh`.

Comment: It works for me. What OS are you using, and what version of bash? (Are you *sure* you're running it with bash, and not some other shell?) Also, try using `trap 'jobs -p | tee /dev/tty | xargs -r kill' EXIT` to see what PIDs are being passed.

Comment: `#!/bin/bash
set -e
yes > /dev/null &
yes > /dev/null &
trap "kill 0" EXIT `
this works

Comment: I am using Ubuntu-18 @GordonDavisson

Comment: @JatinMehrotra it's only killed yes, but no other background jobs.

Comment: i didnt understand `it's only killed yes, but no other background jobs`

Comment: `trap "kill 0" EXIT

./someProcessA &
./someProcessB &

wait` 
This will cause the command kill 0 to run when our script exits. The kill 0 will kill our process, and all of the processes in our process group—which contains our child processes.

Comment: I want to kill child process created by child.sh from main.sh.